# android fit image to fill whole layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an image that has resolution in order to fit whole screen on my test device. When tested with other screen sizes, image fits only width or height and leaves an empty space because it always scales proportional. How could I set image to fit fullscreen also if proportion changes? For example, if my device screen is 3/4, image will be properly scaled on 3/4 displays independent on its resolution. However, for a 16/9 will not fit fullscreen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/blueish"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/splashandroid" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

also tried wrap_content for image layout width

Comment: Did you try android:scaleType="fitXY" in ImageView

Comment: try adding android:scaleType="fitXY"

however, this won't keep the aspect ration of your image

Comment: set width and height of imageview as fill parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in you ImageView, `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or you can use this in you activity means `imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

You can try with this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/blueish"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/splashandroid" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```